# Getting all selected checkboxes' corresponding values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, concatenation

Please have a look at the following code:

```
   $("#saveButton").click(function(){

        $this = $("#tableData").find("input:checked").parent().parent();

        tea = $this.find(".teaCls").text();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chkSelectedValues.php",
            data: "tea=" + tea,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#theField").html(msg);
            }

        });       

    });
```

Now if multiple checkboxes are selected, `tea` and `flower` end up concatenating the `text`s from all those fields. If two checkboxes are selected and one contains the word `some` and the other one contains the word `text`, then finally the `tea` variable gets the value:  `sometext`. But I want `tea` to be an array containing these values (in this case `some` and `text`) since I need to pass them in AJAX request and want to catch easily in `chkSelectedValues.php`

Structure:

```
<table #tableData>
 <tr>
   <td .teaCls></td>
   <td> Checkbox here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  .....
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Solved it.. thanks everybody for help.

```
var md = new Array();
$("input:checkbox").filter(":checked").parent().parent().each(function(){

   md.push($(this).find(".teaCls").text());

});
```

now `md` is my hero!

Comment: are you sure this is solved?  it looks to me like it'll give the text of every `.teaCls` element and doesn't take the `:checked` into account.  Also please see my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure. I've completed the script using it. It might be that you didn't notice `filter(":checked")`

Comment: I noticed it, but then you're ascending to the grandparent (which could be the grandparent of some unchecked boxes too?) before descending again.  It's hard to tell without you including proper markup, though.

Comment: ah, I see - the grandparent is actually the relevant `tr` element.  I thought you had ascended all the way up to the `table` (or rather the implicit `tbody`)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var tea = $(':checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Dwevr/

**EDIT** updated to reflect the OP's clarification:

```
var tea = $(':checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).parent().siblings('.teaCls').text();
}).get();
```

Comment: I don't want the values of checkboxes, I want the text of the other column that are in the same row as the selected checkbox. hope that makes sense

Comment: @sha404 it makes sense, but it's completely unclear from your original question.

Comment: your updated ans should work I think. +1. But I've already solved this. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @sha404 I do think mine is a lot more concise ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot I think this is exactly what you want minus the alert() part for demo purposes. Here is the jsFiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/pT2bP/

```
<table id="tableData">
    <tr>
        <td class="teaCls">FooA</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="BarA"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="teaCls">FooB</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="BarB"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="teaCls">FooC</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="BarC"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="saveButton">Save</button>


$(function() {

    $("#saveButton").click(function() {
        var keyValue = {};

        $("#tableData :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);      
            keyValue[$this.val()] = $this.closest('tr').find('.teaCls').html();
        });
        alert($.param(keyValue));
    });
})
```